# Why *Request.Context() exists and returns a context.Background() in some cases?

Tags: http, go

Please help me to understand the *Request.Context function:

```golang
// Context returns the request's context. To change the context, use
// WithContext.
//
// The returned context is always non-nil; it defaults to the
// background context.
//
// For outgoing client requests, the context controls cancellation.
//
// For incoming server requests, the context is canceled when the
// client's connection closes, the request is canceled (with HTTP/2),
// or when the ServeHTTP method returns.
func (r *Request) Context() context.Context {
    if r.ctx != nil {
        return r.ctx
    }
    return context.Background()
}
```

1. Why do we need this function instead of using a public property on *Request? Is it just for encapsulation so that nobody can change it, making it effectively read-only?
2. When can it happen that the `r.ctx != nil` and `context.Background()` is returned? Isn't every http request guaranteed to have a context the moment it is received? And what is the use of `context.Background()` if it never becomes 'done' due to timeout or cancellation? Basically, why not this instead?

```golang
func (r *Request) Context() context.Context {
    return r.ctx
}
```

Comment: 1. This is a design decision, so opinion based. 2. Request may have nil ctx, context.Background is appropriate according to the documentaton of package context in this case.

Comment: Thanks, @Voler! Also, nobody mentioned that Request can actually be used not only for incoming requests, but also for outgoing requests, and this is when we need this line for returning context.Background()

Comment: "nobody mentioned that Request can actually be used not only for incoming requests, but also for outgoing requests". The official package documentation does so most people assume this is a known fact.

Comment: Yes, but the official documentation does not explicitly mention that every incoming request is guaranteed to have a context assigned to a request, so the context.Background() is used for outgoing requests only, and this is what I was trying to figure out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it is for encapsulation.  Use [WithContext](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.WithContext) or [NewReqeustWithContext](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequestWithContext) to create a request with the context of your choice.
2. `r := &http.Request{}` creates a request with no context.  Ensuring a non-nil return value is a convenience for the caller.  The background context is a suitable default when no other context is specified.